# Eu tenho um ScrolledText com Tkinter, e gostaria de um comando para buscar palavras que estariam dentro dele

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, gui

```
area = ScrolledText(jan, width=800, height=400)
```

> Aqui eu tenho um ScrolledText, que nada mais é que uma caixa de texto com uma barra de rolagem, digamos que digitei bastante conteudo dentro dela e gostaria de buscar por tal nome ex: combustivel, ao realizada funçao apareceria algo como uma Entry e assim digitaria oq estou procurando ao finalizar apareceria onde digitei tal palavra uma especie de "Ctrl" + "F" no ScrolledText
>
> Consegui detectar se o conteudo inserido em uma entry esta na caixa de texto mas nao consigo mostrar apenas a linha do conteudo, veja o exemplo

```
ctf = Entry(top)
ctf.place(x=0, y=0)

def serch():
    cont = ctf.get()
    dent_text = area.get(1.0, END)
    if cont in todo:
        messagebox.showinfo(title="Pesquisa", message=("Aqui devia aparecer
 toda a linha mas se eu colocar ou cont para exibir mostrara apenas o 
 digitado na entry, se colocar dent_text, todo conteudo da ScrolledText sera 
 mostrado, eu queria exibir apenas a linha em que o cont esta)

csc = Button(top, text="OK", command=serch)
csc.place(x=130, y=0)
```

Comment: [link] http://www.bitforestinfo.com/2017/05/how-to-create-find-and-findall-features-in-tkinter-text-widget-python-magicstick-text-editor-part-9.html

Encontrei algo parecido mas nao consegui entender muito bem a ideia

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O **"comando"** que você está procurando é o método `search()` o qual possui os parâmetros:

```py
search(self, pattern, index, stopindex=None,
       forwards=None, backwards=None, exact=None,
       regexp=None, nocase=None, count=None, elide=None)
```

Montei um exemplo realizado a pesquisa em widgets do tipo `Text` e `ScrolledText`.

Não segui o seu código porque ele não é um exemplo minimo funcional.

`Pipfle` que foi utilizado:

```
[[source]]
name = "pypi"
url = "https://pypi.org/simple"
verify_ssl = true

[dev-packages]
pylint = "*"
autopep8 = "*"

[packages]

[requires]
python_version = "3.6"
```

Código:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""Busca de palavras ou letras com Tkinter."""
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import messagebox
from tkinter.scrolledtext import ScrolledText


class Application(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        super().__init__(master)
        self.master = master
        self.pack(expand=True, fill=tk.BOTH, padx=5, pady=5)
        self.create_widgets()

    def create_widgets(self):
        # Frame para organizar o entry e o button.
        frame_search = tk.Frame(self)
        frame_search.pack(side=tk.TOP, expand=True, fill=tk.X)

        self.entry_search = tk.Entry(master=frame_search)
        self.entry_search.pack(side=tk.LEFT, expand=True, fill=tk.X, padx=(0, 10))

        button_search = tk.Button(master=frame_search)
        button_search['text'] = 'Buscar'
        button_search['command'] = self.on_button_clicked
        button_search.pack(side=tk.RIGHT, fill=tk.X)

        # Frame para o ScrolledText.
        frame_text_area = tk.Frame(self)
        frame_text_area.pack(side=tk.BOTTOM, expand=True, fill=tk.BOTH)

        # self.text_area = tk.Text(frame_text_area)
        # self.text_area.insert(tk.END, 'ola mundo')
        # self.text_area.pack(side=tk.BOTTOM, pady=10)

        self.text_area = ScrolledText(frame_text_area)
        self.text_area.insert(tk.END, 'ola mundo')
        self.text_area.pack(side=tk.BOTTOM, pady=10)

    def on_button_clicked(self):
        # Contador para exibir quantas ocorrências houveram.
        words = 0

        # Pesquisa se inicia na linha 1, coluna 0.
        start = '1.0'

        # Coletando texto digitado no entry.
        entry = self.entry_search.get()

        # Se o entry estiver vazio não existe a necessidade de se pesquisar.
        if not entry:
            messagebox.showinfo('Alerta', 'Entry não pode estar vazio.')
        else:
            # Removendo a tag, pois a cada nova
            # pesquisa a posição pode variar.
            self.text_area.tag_delete('found')

            # Verificando o tamanho do texto digitado no entry.
            # Tamanho será utilizado para posicionamento.
            word_size = len(entry)

            # Laço de repetição ficará ativo até percorrer todas as posições.
            while True:
                # Realizando a pesquisa
                pos = self.text_area.search(pattern=entry, index=start, stopindex=tk.END, count=True)

                # Quando não houver mais posições é
                # exibindo o dialogo e o loop é encerado.
                if not pos:
                    messagebox.showinfo(
                        'Pesquisa finalizada',
                        f'{words} localizado(s) com: "{entry}"'
                    )
                    print(f'A pesquisa chegou ao fim {words} localizado(s)\n')
                    break

                print(f'Palavra/letra localizada na linha {pos[0]} e na coluna de {pos[2]}')

                # Adicionando a uma tag na posição em que o texto foi localizado.
                # Aqui está sendo utilizando ``word_size = len(entry)``
                # para determinar a posição final da cor de fundo do texto.
                self.text_area.tag_add('found', pos, (pos + f'+{word_size}c'))

                # Incrementando o contador.
                words += 1

                # Alterando o valor da variável ``start`` para que em
                # algum momento ele seja superior a stopindex=tk.END.
                start = pos + '+1c'

            # Configurando a tag que foi inserida em ``self.text_area``.
            self.text_area.tag_config('found', background='yellow')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.title('Busca de palavras ou letras com Tkinter')
    app = Application(master=root)
    app.mainloop()
```

> **obs**: O código apresentado tem apenas o intuito de exemplificar uma busca simples.

Lembre-se de analisar e alterar o código conforme as necessidades do seu projeto.

Caso encontre algum erro, ou mesmo se julgar que o código não atende a pergunta, lembre-se de avisar para que a resposta possa ser alterada ou mesmo removida.

Comment: testei seu codigo e realmente é dessa forma que quero, porem meu codigo fonte nao ultilizo o metodo self meu codigo é bem simples mas na hora de passar seu conhecimento para meu codigo mesmo com a versao mesma da sua continuei tendo problemas tem como me passar seu email para que eu envie o codigo fonte completo? creio que isso ajudaria muito

Comment: natorsc@gmail.com e no meu perfil tem outras formas de contato também:
https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/93029/renato-cruz?tab=profile